# Structurally replace methods that have a parameter name starting with

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, structural-search

So in my code i have the following instances

```
view1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.is_bag);
view2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.is_bag);
view3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
```

I'm trying to do a structural replace for all the `.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.*` methods alone. Here's what i'm trying so far:

Search template:

```
$Instance$.setBackgroundResource($Parameter$)
```

Edit variables:

```
$Instance$  -> Text/regexp   = <empty> (which i understand = .*)
$Parameter$ -> Text/regexp   = .*R\.drawable\..*
           Minimum count = 1     // Minimum one Foo parameter
           Maximum count = 1     // Maximum one Foo parameter
```

For some reason this refuses to match anything. if i changed `$Parameter$` to be empty or `.*` then it matches all `setBackgroundResource` methods.

Would someone know what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Odd one, it appears that the Text/regexp for $Parameter$ only works on the actual variable name (everything after it's containing static Types ie R.drawable). If you set Text/regexp to `is_bag` it will find all of the ones ending with `is_bag`. Curious...  Maybe just use a regular expression search and replace for this one.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$Instance$.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.$Parameter$)
```

With both `Instance` and `Parameter` empty.

Comment: hmm i did try that, for some reason when i switch to that, `setBackgroundResource(R.color.*)` also gets flagged.

I wonder if it's because it has something to do with R.x.x etc in Android Studio being resource constants?

Comment: i suppose it wouldn't explain why having R.drawable explicitly flags both then. hmm potentially a bug?

Comment: Good possibility for a bug. Just tested with inner static classes that aren't in R. Got results for the entire enclosing class when I searched for a specific inner class http://imgur.com/a/9c7Xk. It appears that the inner static class is ignored in the search, and it searches across everything declared at the most top level class ( ie. R in your case ) Bug report! @KaushikGopal

Comment: Some fixes were made in this area in the just released IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2, so it is possible this query should work correctly there hopefully. I assume the fixes will end up in Android Studio at some point too.